# What is this swift mailer error

Tags: php, regex, email, html-email, swiftmailer

I was getting this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception ‘Swift_RfcComplianceException’ with message ‘Address in mailbox given [] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.’ in..
```

resolved by this post

http://royalsumit.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-fix-swift-mailer-error-address.html

I commented out the lines as shown and now my mail works. I just want to know what this error is about and if commenting out these lines will have any repurcussions.

Lines I commented out:

```
private function _assertValidAddress($address)
  {
    if (!preg_match('/^' . $this->getGrammar()->getDefinition('addr-spec') . '$/D',
      $address))
    {
     /* throw new Swift_RfcComplianceException(
        'Address in mailbox given [' . $address .
        '] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.'
        );*/
    }
  }
```

Could this have any possibility to negatively affect other aspects of my mailer?

Comment: What data were you feeding to Swiftmailer in the first place? The error message looks like something essential was left empty.

Comment: @Pekka웃  Like this ->


`->setFrom(array('no-reply@test.net' => 'me'))

  ->setTo(array('me@gmail.com', $my_email))

  ->setBcc(array('me_other@gmail.com'=>'meAgain'))

  ->setBody($order_table_to_mail);`

Answer (score 0):

You get this error cause `replay-to` in the mail header is empty.

Just set this value and everything should work fine.

As you can see it still works when you just comment out this line since it is only a validation, but you should really fix it.